# Is there a folder layout structure for Django websites?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get an overview of a Django website application structure. The way I have done this in the past with other frameworks (Symfony, RoR etc) is to look at the application folder structure, work out which bits go where, and then work my way on from there onwards.

I have been searching online for similar info about Django website folder structure - but have been unable to find one. Is there a recommended folder structure for Django apps? - and if yes, where I can obtain the document that details this?

Comment: -1: Django-admin has a start project command: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/django-admin/#startproject-projectname.  You just run it -- it creates the structure for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes see

[Folder structure for a Django project](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/BestPracticesToWorkWith3rdPartyAppsAndMakingYoursPortable#UPDATED:FolderstructureforaDjangoproject)

also see

[Writing your first Django app, part 1 - Creating a project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project)

startproject script by default generates

```
mysite/
    __init__.py
    manage.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the tutorial on [djangoproject.com](http://www.djangoproject.com) - the directory structure is pretty clearly stated.

Comment: Been there already, couldn't find it (hence this question). can you provide a link where the folder structure (+ what goes where) is discussed?

Comment: It is literally on the first page of the tutorial.  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project

Answer (score 0):

I think the philosophy was letting you have control over that. You can take a look at djangoproject's structure for inspiration: 
http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/djangoproject.com/django_website